# Post page 404 with WP e-commerce plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce, custom-post-type

I have an issue with WP e-commerce and post details page.

When I change Permalinks to Post name OR Custom Structure to `/%postname%/`, my all post details page go to **404** error, though product details page and all other Pages are working fine.

Also post details page is working fine if I change Permalinks to Default one i.e. `?p=123`

current htaccess is as below

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Is is on local host ?

Comment: No, it is on my staging server

Comment: Have gone through the rewrite rule in htaccess file ?

Comment: I have the default rules set in .htaccess

Comment: Yes, I have the same code, also added it in my question. Do I need to change anything?

Comment: Is it rewritable by youe host provider ?

Comment: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)$ http://yoursitename.com/$1`

Add above code in to your .htaccess file.

Comment: I do not want to 301 redirection, and btw your above code will go in infinite loop.

Comment: You should mention in your question with highlighting note **without 301 redirection**